# Access Sidekiq arguments from inside worker

Tags: sidekiq

Can I access the arguments that a Sidekiq worker was called with from inside the worker?

My use-case is that I want to reschedule a job using `perform_in` if a certain condition is met, but if should work from inside a module method where I don't know the original args that the worker was called with.

Example:

```rb
class MyWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include MyRescheduler

  def perform(a, b, c)
    do_reschedule
  end
end

module MyRescheduler
  def do_reschedule
    # At this point I'd like to reschedule the job
    # with the arguments it was called with.
    self.class.perform_in 1.minute, ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has the splat operator for that.

```rb
def perform(*args)
  self.class.perform_in 1.minute, *args
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Mike! Unfortunately in my case, I don't know the arguments to the worker (and I can't change them to use the splat operator). What I noticed, though, is that when an error occurs at the point where I'm trying to reschedule, the error report (in Rollbar) includes the args the job was called with - so they must be stored somewhere, right? :)